# Unable to delete PDF after merging using Itext 5

Tags: java, pdf, merge, itext, concatenation

I use the Itext5 library to merge PDFs. Once the merge is complete I want to be able to delete the PDFs, but I cannot delete them yet I have used reader.close().
My Code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("CONCAT PDF");
        pdfConcat2("C:\\Users\\File1.pdf",
                "C:\\Users\\File2.pdf",
                "C:\\Users\\File_FINAL.pdf");
        System.out.println("-------------ACTION DELETE");
        if (FileTools.deleteFile("C:\\Users\\File1.pdf")) {
            System.out.println("DELETE PDF OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("DELETE PDF NOK");
        }
        if (FileTools.deleteFile("C:\\Users\\File2.pdf")) {
            System.out.println("DELETE PDF OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("DELETE PDF NOK");
        }
}

public static void pdfConcat2(String pathFile1, String pathFile2, String destinationPDF) {
        //
        Document document = null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        PdfCopy copy = null;
        PdfReader reader = null;

        //
        try {
            document = new Document();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationPDF);
            copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outputStream);
            document.open();
//          for (int i = 0; i < mergeFile.size(); i++) {
            reader = new PdfReader(pathFile1);
            copy.addDocument(reader);
            copy.freeReader(reader);
            reader.close();
            reader = new PdfReader(pathFile2);
            copy.addDocument(reader);
            copy.freeReader(reader);
            reader.close();
//          }
            outputStream.flush();
            document.close();
            outputStream.close();
            copy.flush();
            copy.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I always have the same result :
DELETE PDF NOK

Do you have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: I tested this code with JDK1.8 and it works, but not in OPENJDK17 or in JDK12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contourned the problem, adding FileinputStream in the PDFReader. There are a problem with Itext5 since java9.

```
public static void pdfConcat2(String pathFile1, String pathFile2, String destinationPDF) {
    //
    Document document = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    PdfCopy copy = null;
    PdfReader reader = null;

    //
    try {
        document = new Document();
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationPDF);
        copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pathFile1));
        copy.addDocument(reader);
        copy.freeReader(reader);
        reader.close();
        reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pathFile2));
        copy.addDocument(reader);
        copy.freeReader(reader);
        reader.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        document.close();
        outputStream.close();
        copy.flush();
        copy.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```